# 4900, a particularly square number

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I read in "Letters to a young mathematician" that 4900 is the only square integer that is the sum of consecutive squares (I believe he meant by that "starting from 1", but maybe that's not even necessary). I did a quick run through with a python script and of course this seems totally devoid of a computational pattern. Why is 4900 (and 1 of course) the only number such that this works?

I did find out that the sum of squares is the following...

$\sum^{n}_{i=1} i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CannonballProblem.html


Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper21.pdf

Comment: $1^2+2^2+...+24^2=70^2=4900.$

Comment: Yes, I know that it's the sum from 1 to 24 squared, that was easy, I'm wondering WHY it's the only answer.

Comment: Jonas, you could just put that as the answer, that'll get me where I need to be. The CannonballProblem link doesn't help unless you have the papers.

Comment: It seems no one has picked up on the question of whether "starting from 1" is necessary. Of course, it is; trivially, every square integer is the sum of (one) consecutive square(s). Slightly less trivially, $5^2=3^2+4^2$, $29^2=20^2+21^2$ (the first two members of an infinite sequence of examples obtainable via Pell). There's also $38^2+39^2+\dots+48^2=143^2$, again the first in an infinite sequence of square sums of 11 consecutive squares, and many, many more. 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a classical Diophantine equation (Mordell, *Diophantine Equations*, p. 258). Apart from n = 0, 1, -1, there is only the solution n = 24. Proofs by G. N. Watson (1919), W. Ljunggren (1952).

There is some history in http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper21.pdf .

Answer (score 12):

I remember vaguely that the equation $1^2+\dots+24^2=70^2$ gives a construction of the Leech lattice (one has to consider one of the two even neighbours  of the lattice $\mathbb Z \frac{w}{70}+\Lambda'$ where $w=(1,2,\dots,24)$ and $\Lambda'=\lbrace z\in\mathbb Z^{24}|\langle z,w\rangle\in70\mathbb Z\rbrace$) which is a rather unique and exceptional structure.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice
for an outline of this construction; it uses the
vector $(0,1,2,\ldots,24,70)$ in the Lorentzian
even unimodular lattice of rank 26 and signature 24.


Comment: John Baez also has a couple of articles about the number 24 and the Leech lattice in his excellent expository articles - http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/numbers/24.pdf and http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week95.html